# How can I logout user after delete with Laravel?

Tags: laravel

What is the correct way to logout user after I delete his data in Laravel? I would not like to delete him before, in case of delete process goes with errors.

When I am having this code:

```
    if($this->userManipulator->softDeleteUser(Auth::user())){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect(url('login'));
    }
```

it works fine in the app, but does not work correctly during testing.

Comment: Someone else might know of a solution, but I personally don't think this is possible. `Auth::logout` looks for the logged in user but after `deleted_at` is no longer null, `Auth` won't be able to located them because Eloquent treats them as deleted (considering you're using `softDeletes`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you must log the user out of your application first since once deleted Eloquent won't be able to locate/logout the user.

Below is a solution that addresses your concern about what to do if the `delete` fails. It might need adjustment depending on how you have things setup, but this concept *will* work:

```
// Get the user
$user = Auth::user();

// Log the user out
Auth::logout();

// Delete the user (note that softDeleteUser() should return a boolean for below)
$deleted = $this->userManipulator->softDeleteUser($user);

if ($deleted) {
    // User was deleted successfully, redirect to login
    return redirect(url('login'));
} else {
    // User was NOT deleted successfully, so log them back into your application! Could also use: Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
    Auth::login($user);

    // Redirect them back with some data letting them know it failed (or handle however you need depending on your setup)
    return back()->with('status', 'Failed to delete your profile');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, `Auth` won't be able to located them because Eloquent treats them as deleted.

Solution: You should logout user before delete.

```
$user = \User::find(Auth::user()->id);

Auth::logout();

if ($user->delete()) {

     return Redirect::route('home');
}
```

Comment: Actually that is something I knew myself. The problem is what should I do, in case user delete process fails?